# Detect clicks of images inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

I cant figure out why this isn't working. It's probably something simple. The iframe is from the same domain as parent page.

I know I can use jQuery, but I want to learn to do it in pure JavaScript.

My code so far:

```
document.getElementById('my_iframe').onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = function() {
        alert("image in iframe was clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the frame business for a second, and look at this code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').onclick = function() {
```

Will that ever work? No. You are getting an object (a `NodeList`, to be precise) containing all the `img` elements in the document. You are adding an `onclick` property to that object. Not to the elements themselves: to an object that points to them. The function will never be fired because it is never applied to any elements.

You should do exactly the same as you normally would: loop though all the images you've found and apply the function to them individually.

```
var onclickFn = function() {
        alert("image in iframe was clicked");
    },
    images = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = onclickFn;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation (I am trying to learn pure javascript instead of jquery...)

Comment: You're very welcome, of course. (You know, you can say that you think an answer is useful by upvoting it by clicking the up arrow. I notice from your profile that you have never cast any votes, so I thought I'd let you know if you weren't aware!)

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday, will check into upvoting, when to use and so on :)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName` is returning a **collection** of images.  You can't just set a click handler on the entire collection.  You need to loop through them one at a time.

```
var allimgs  = document.getElementById('my_iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < allimgs.length; i++)  {
    allimgs[i].onclick = function() {
       alert("image in iframe was clicked");
    };
}
```